# How to Update a model while creating another model using one form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Pls i need help here.
i have 2 models:- due_job and outgoing_job
due_job has_many outgoing_jobs
outgoing_job belongs_to due_job.
Im trying to update a user's outgoing_job as done while at the same time create a due_job for another user.
My models:

```
class DueJob < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :outgoing_jobs
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :outgoing_jobs
end

class OutgoingJob < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :outgoing_jobs
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :outgoing_jobs
end
```

Controllers:

```
class OutgoingJobsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @outgoing_job = OutgoingJob.new
        @outgoing_jobs = OutgoingJob.all
    end

    def new 
        @outgoing_job = OutgoingJob.new 
    end 

    def create
        @outgoing_job = OutgoingJob.new(outgoing_job_params)
        respond_to do |format|
        
            if @outgoing_job.save   
                flash.now[:success] = "saved"
                format.html {redirect_to current_user}
                format.json {render json: @outgoing_job, status: :created, location: @outgoing_job}
            else 
                flash[:danger] = "not saved"
                format.html {redirect_to root_path}
                format.json {render json: @outgoing_job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    def show
        @outgoing_job = OutgoingJob.find(params[:id])
    end 

    def update 
        @outgoing_job = OutgoingJob.find(params[:id])
        respond_to do |format|
            if @outgoing_job.update(outgoing_job_params)
                format.html { redirect_to '/users/outgoing_job_dashboard', notice: 'job updated' }
                format.json {render action: 'show', status: :ok, location: @outgoing_job }
            else
                format.html { render action: 'edit'}
                format.json { render json: @outgoing_job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
            end
        end  
    end

    def destroy
        @outgoing_job.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html {redirect_to current_user}
            format.json { head :no_content}
        end
    end



    private
    def outgoing_job_params
        params.require(:outgoing_job).permit(:outgoing_job_value, 
            :sent,
            :confirmed,
            :done,
            :due_job_id,
            :user_id )
    end
 end
```

the controller for due_jobs is essentially same.

However, when i do this in my view:

```
<% OutgoingJob.all.each do |od| %>
    <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Done By</th>
                <th>Done for</th>
                <th>Beneficiary</th>
                <th>Amount proposed</th>
                <th>Amount to paid</th>
                <th>Create due job</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <% if (od.confirmed == true) && (od.done== false) %>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= od.id %></td>
                    <td><%= od.user.first_name %> <%= od.user.last_name %></td>
                    <td><%= od.due_job.user.first_name %> <%= od.due_job.user.last_name %></td>
                    <td><%= od.due_job.user.user_detail %></td>
                    <td>$ <%= number_with_delimiter(od.outgoing_job_value, delimiter: ',') %> </td>
                    <td> <%= --- %> </td>

                    <td>
                        <%= simple_form_for (DueJob.new) do |u| %>
                            <%= u.hidden_field :due_job_value, value: od.outgoing_job_value  %>
                            <%= u.hidden_field :user_id, value: od.user.id %>
                            <%= u.fields_for od  do |f| %>
                            <%= f.hidden_field :done, value: true %>
                        <%end%>
                        <%= u.submit "create", class: "btn btn-success" %>
                      <%end%>
                   </td>
                   <td><%= link_to "View", od %></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        <%end%>
    </table>
    .....
```

Using nested form i am able to create a new record for DueJob tho, but it doesnt update outgoing_job. What am i missing pls?

Comment: You might have better luck if you clean up your code. Things like this: `if (od.confirmed == true) && (od.done== false)` ought to look more like this: `if od.confirmed? &! od.done?`. Chunks like `<%end%>` should be more clearly written: `<% end %>`. And for the love of all things holy, consistent indentation should be used so we're not looking at word soup.

Comment: Thanks @coreyward. Duly noted. I will try my best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you make use of [ActiveRecord callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) to relegate some of the code to your models (I doubt that trying to do everything from one view is the way to go).

In your model for `DueJob` add something like:

```
class DueJob < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Register a callback to execute every time you create a new DueJob
  after_create :update_done_flag_on_outgoing_job

  # ... and add some code for that callback.
  def update_done_flag_on_outgoing_job
    outgoing_job.update_attribute :done, true
  end
```

Just from reading your source code, I was struggling to understand how you identify the connections between the newly created `DueJob` and the specific `OutgoingJob` record that you want to update. Like @coreyward pointed out, it would be helpful if you could present your code a bit more neatly. If you can't use my example snippet *as is*, I guess you can always adapt the `update_done_flag_on_outgoing_job` method to your needs.

Hope you find that helpful.